# class from thephpleague Csv library installed with composer not found

Tags: php, csv, composer-php

I installed composer and I'm being able to install and use monolog as the [Basic usage guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) explains. But it doesn't work for the [Csv library from The Php League](http://csv.thephpleague.com/).

Here are the steps I did:

#### 1) Create an empty directory

#### 2) Install there monolog

```
$ composer require monolog/monolog
```

#### 3) Check it works

Following [the composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

From the php interactive console (initialized with `php -a`):

```
php > require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
php > $log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
php > $log->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('app.log', Monolog\Logger::WARNING));
php > $log->addWarning('Foo');
```

Then, I verified the `app.log` content from the console:

```
$ cat app.log
[2016-02-09 00:55:06] name.WARNING: Foo [] []
```

#### 4) Install csv from leage

```
$ composer require league/csv
```

#### 5) Check it works

Following [league/csv documentation](http://csv.thephpleague.com/instantiation/#abstractcsvcreatefrompath).

From the php interactive console (you know, `php -a`):

```
php > require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
php > use League\Csv\Reader;
php > $reader = Reader::createFromPath('file.csv');
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Reader' not found in php shell code on line 1
```

#### Why and How?

- Why does it works for `monolog/monolog` but doesn't for `league/csv`?
- How to use `league/csv` from the php interactive console?

Comment: did you try composer dump-autoload??

Comment: @Drudge once. I'll try again... Tried, but fails the same. What I did this time was: 1) Install league/csv in a fresh directory; 2) run composer dump-autoload; 3) try to use it as step 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like use statements don't properly work when using the PHP interactive shell. Otherwise, the use statement for `Reader` would have been catched and the error would be something like *"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'League\Csv\Reader' not found in php shell code on line 1"*

To try it out in the shell, use the FQCN (or QCN) as you did with your monolog example:

```
php > require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
php > $reader = League\Csv\Reader::createFromPath('file.csv');
```

Comment: I know this is old but if someone sees this I would love the help, how can someone do this as part of a PHP file, not the command line.